# android chronometer start from last stop

Tags: android, chronometer

Although there are answered questions about this, none REALLY answers the following:
I want the android chronometer to start from the last stop, NOT to continue counting time.
I try the following, but IT DOES NOT WORK :-(

```js
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
  long stopTime = 0;

  public void startChronometer(View view) {
    long elapsedTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - stopTime;
    ((Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.mycrono)).setBase(elapsedTime);
    ((Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.mycrono)).start();
  }
  public void stopChronometer(View view) {
    stopTime = findViewById(R.id.mycrono).getBaseline();
    ((Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.mycrono)).stop();
  }

  ............. // standard android methods
```

results crazy numbers...

Answer (score 0):

i am using chronometer to start from last time l3 which is in second

```
chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()
                            - (0 * 60000 + l3 * 1000));
                    chronometer.start();
```

Comment: 0*60000=0..  so what do you mean by this??

Comment: actually 0*6000 means if you want to use last time in mints instead of second than you can use like this l3*6000

Answer (score 0):

This is works for me. I have 3 buttons (Start, pause, stop).

```
    private var stopTime : Long = 0


    /*Put this in your method, where you want to handle the buttons. 
      I worked with FloatingActionsButtons*/

    fab_start.setOnClickListener {
            chronometer.base = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + stopTime
            chronometer.start()
        }
    fab_pause.setOnClickListener {
            stopTime = chronometer.base - SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()
            chronometer.stop()
        }
    fab_stop.setOnClickListener {
            chronometer.base = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()
            stopTime = 0
            chronometer.stop()
        }
```